# How to display payment method form in myaccount page without quote or order?

Tags: php, magento

In Magento 1.6 Community Edition:

I want to display all payment methods into my account section with my custom module.
Problem is that all payment methods are displaying correct but payment method form displays only when there are some items in cart.

and this query returns nothing:

`$this->getChildHtml('payment.method.'.$_code)`

Comment: Why do You want to display any form? Do You want to let users pre-select their desired payment method? Then You will have to implement the form from the scratch within a new module/extending the account module... Payment method form is destined for the purpose of creating a new order...

Comment: I want to give user choice of payment methods instead of the preselected. So user can choose payment method for second level process.

Comment: I guess that You'd need to implement one from the scratch (You can inspire Yourself in the default one for first level process)... I do not know Magento but everybody is singing about it so it shouldn't be any problem...